# Trying to generate an array with an exec function in Python throws an error

Tags: python, list, dictionary, exec

I am trying to generate the next code in Python:

```
atribute_name = 'atr1'
exec("list_%s = []", atribute_name)
```

So the expected result should be:

```
list_atr1 = []
```

But when I execute it I get the next error message:

```
TypeError: exec: arg 2 must be a dictionary or None
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: you probably meant to write `exec("list_%s = []" % atribute_name)` (`%` instead of `,`). better: use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: [exec built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comma, you should replace it with `%` for string concatenation.

```
exec("list_%s = []" % atribute_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing second argument for `exec` function.
Instead you just need to format your string.
Below sample code can help you.

```
atribute_name = 'atr1'
str1 = "list_%s = []" % atribute_name

print str1
exec(str1)
print list_atr1
```